# Visual studio can't find my file even though the directory is correct

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I am trying to import a netCDF4 file to VS Code using a basic script that works in PyCharm. I know that the directory is correct as I went to the file itself and copied the file but it still won't find it. Here's the code is there something wrong with it.

```py
import netCDF4 as nc

fn = "C:\tmp\VCSN-mslp-1972.nc"
ds = nc.Dataset(fn)

print(ds)
```

Comment: I forgot to add the output so here it is.         
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: b'C:\tmp\\VCSN-mslp-1972.nc'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following code, it worked on my machine:

```
import netCDF4 as nc
ds = nc.Dataset("C:\\Users\\...\\Desktop\\a.nc","w")
print(ds)
```

[image]

Comment: @FlyingSquirrle. Glad my answer helps you, do you mind marking it as an answer? it will make more people with the same questions reach this solution.